# List IndexError after processing all data with Python 3

Tags: list, indexing, range

Here is the code:

```
name = input("Enter Molecule ID: ")

name_in = name+'.lac.dat'
print(name_in)

atm_chg = []

with open(name_in) as f:
    # skip two lines
    f.readline()
    f.readline()
    for line in f.readlines():
        atm_chg.append(float( line.split()[-1] ))
```

This is to process input for a larger Python program.

The input is:

```
LOEWDIN ATOMIC CHARGES
----------------------
   0 C :   -0.780631
   1 H :    0.114577
   2 Br:    0.309802
   3 Cl:    0.357316
   4 F :   -0.001065
```

Finally the runtime messages are:

```
runfile('/home/comp/Apps/Python/Testing/ReadFile_2.py', wdir='/home/comp/Apps/Python/Testing')

Enter Molecule ID: A
A.lac.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-8c665940b39f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/comp/Apps/Python/Testing/ReadFile_2.py', wdir='/home/comp/Apps/Python/Testing')

  File "/home/comp/Apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/comp/Apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/comp/Apps/Python/Testing/ReadFile_2.py", line 27, in <module>
    atm_chg.append(float( line.split()[-1] ))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

In spite of the errors there is an entry in the Variable Explorer (Spyder IDE):

```
[-0.780631, 0.114577, 0.309802, 0.357316, -0.001065]
```

which is exactly what I require.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is, exactly.  Are you trying to get rid of the IndexError messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is probably crashing because it's trying to process an empty line beyond the last line of data. You can fix this by making sure the line is non-empty before processing it:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if line.strip(): # is the line non-empty, ignoring white space
        atm_chg.append(float( line.split()[-1] ))
```

Comment: @Steve You're welcome, glad it helped! If you want, you have the option of marking this answer as "correct" by clicking the checkmark on the left.